# JSForce Visualforce connection

Tags: visualforce, javascript, browser, jsforce

So I am writing a visualforce app that is trying to use the jsforce. But I am having issues testing the jsforce library on the visualforce page.

Here is a test I am trying to run from the visualforce page

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsforce/1.7.1/jsforce.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var conn = new jsforce.Connection({ accessToken: '{!$API.Session_Id}', version: '39.0' });
  conn.query('SELECT count(Id) FROM Account', function(err, res) {
    if (err) { return console.error(err); }
    console.log(res);
  });
</script>
```

When the page loads and I try and execute the query above I get a 503 error. Am I missing something here?

#### Full Visualforce Page

This is per @RedDevil 's request

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" docType="html-5.0" controller="CC_HomeController" extensions="CC_AttachmentUpload" action="{!forwardToLogin}" >
  <apex:composition template="{!$Site.Template}">
    <!-- Page Title -->
    <apex:define name="pagetitle">Home</apex:define>
    <!-- Define Body -->
    <apex:define name="body" >
      <!-- Visualforce Stuff... -->
    </apex:define>
  </apex:composition>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsforce/1.7.1/jsforce.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  var conn = new jsforce.Connection({ accessToken: '{!$API.Session_Id}', version: '39.0' });
  conn.query('SELECT count(Id) FROM Account', function(err, res) {
    if (err) { return console.error(err); }
    console.log(res);
  });
  </script>

</apex:page>
```

#### Error in Chrome Dev Console

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)`

#### Session ID Value

This is an example of the value that `{!$API.Session_Id}` is being replaced with

`00D180000008jqp!AQkAQEChgHoPYYNZas4V108S.3woZGBQ0AohF7fRMSY1xErVYJOeH5iW5mpJWsx2PR5JR0BGPbpzIk_wyBJbN9MO0XQfVcmf`

Answer (score 1):

i just saw your page.I saved it my sanndbox and it errored out because i did not have the controller associated on the VF page. Now i removed it and previewed it from my developer sandbox and it gave the correct output. How are you testing it? Are you testing it using a site? or did you preview the page from developer console. The reason i am asking this is if you look at the first line in script tag of jsforce its looking for a session id. It will only be available if you have authenticated your user. It will work from developer console preview but it wont work from an unauthenticated site

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. I am testing it on a site that I am logging into via salesforce. Are you asking if `{!$API.Session_Id}` is outputing a value  @RedDevil?

Comment: Yes that's correct

Comment: Okay then yes, I am getting a proper value for session id in place of `{!$API.Session_Id}`. I have updated the question with more information about that variable. @RedDevil

Comment: Any thoughts @RedDevil